# Populating columns of a window

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, treeviewitem, treelistview

What I am trying to do is populate two columns in a window.  This columns will have the name of the global variable and the path it to it.  I am having problems displaying what I need in the windows.

```
        <TabItem Header="Global Variables" GotFocus="GlobalVariablesTab_GotFocus">
           <dc:TreeListView Name="tvwGlobalVariables"  dc:ColumnLayoutManager.Enabled="True" >
                <dc:TreeListView.Columns>

                    <!--First Column. -->
                   <dc:StdGridViewColumn Header="Variable" Width="200" >

                         <dc:StdGridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                             <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                         </dc:StdGridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </dc:StdGridViewColumn>

                    <!-- Second Column-->
                     <dc:StdGridViewColumn Header="Result" dc:ColumnRange.IsFillColumn="True"/>

               </dc:TreeListView.Columns> 
            </dc:TreeListView> 
        </TabItem>
```

This is the tab that has the area I need to populate.  The first column for the name and the second will be for the path. I may be missing something as well.

```
    private void GlobalVariablesTab_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        lvGlobals.Items.Clear();
        sman = SchemaManager.SchemaManager.GetInstance();
        IEnumerator enumerator = sman.GetGlobalVariableEnumerator();
        while (enumerator.MoveNext()) 
        {
            DictionaryEntry entry = (DictionaryEntry) enumerator.Current;
            ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();//new string[] {entry.Key.ToString(), entry.Value.ToString()});
            lvi.Tag = entry.Key.ToString() + entry.Value.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Currently I have lvi holding both parts but I will need one part to go to the first column and the other part to the other column.  I don't intend to keep lvi if I don't need it.  Either way I need to get `entry.key` displayed in the first column and `entry.value` in the second.  Any ideas?

Comment: If anyone needs any more information just let me know, I added what i though was relevant but I don't know much about all this so It was just an assumption.

Comment: I can give you code to display two columns in a regular listview. 

It is hard to tell what is wrong with your code since you use a proprietary TreeListView that may not even work. But just guessing from looking at your code I see two potential issues.

First, if you use datatemplates for CellTemplates you want to use databinding and not mess with ListViewItems. Setting Tag on a ListViewItems will not result in anything being displayed.

Comment: The 2 columns is all i can display i would like to write to those columns could you explain how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what the SchemaManager is so I just used a Hashtable with some dummy data to get an enumerator with some dictionary entries. Below sample code uses a regular WPF listview with two columns with no formatting to keep it simple.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TwoColsDemo.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Height="300" Width="300">

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Data}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridView.Columns>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Key" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Key}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Value" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Value}" />
                </GridView.Columns>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;

namespace TwoColsDemo
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Hashtable sman = new Hashtable();
            sman.Add("Key1", "Value1");
            sman.Add("Key2", "Value2");

            Data = new List<DictionaryEntry>();

            IEnumerator enumerator = sman.GetEnumerator();
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                DictionaryEntry entry = (DictionaryEntry)enumerator.Current;
                Data.Add(entry);
            }

            DataContext = this;
        }

        public List<DictionaryEntry> Data { get; private set; }
    }
}
```